# PHP Sorting nearest coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table in a PHP webservice containing longitude and latitude.
I want to send the user only the, let's say, 5 closest coordinates.
I wrote the method which calculates a distance from coordinates to the ones the user sent in the POST request, but I'm not sure on how to sort it and only send back a few.

Here is the distance method:

```
function  distance($longToCompare,$latToCompare) {
    $dlong = $request_long - $longToCompare;
    $dlat = $request_lat - $latToCompare;
    $a = pow(sin($dlat/2)) + cos($latToCompare)*cos($request_lat)*pow(sin($dlong/2));
    $c = 2*atan2(sqrt($a),sqrt(1-$a));
    return 6373*$c; 
}
```

and the user currently gets the whole DB (for now, while developing it's small, but in the future it could be rather big)

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Coordinates");
$coordinates = array ();
while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $coordinates[] = $e;
}
print (json_encode($coordinates));
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? I'm rather new to PHP, I know I can create a custom sorting using uasort, but i'm not quite sure on how to use it using this distance function.

EDIT:
Using @Norse 's solution, the current query is:

```
$request_long = $_POST['longitude'];
$request_lat = $_POST['latitude'];
    $km = 0.5;
        $query = "SELECT *, 
    ( 6373 * acos( cos( radians('$request_lat') ) * 
    cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
    cos( radians( longitude ) - 
    radians('$request_long') ) + 
    sin( radians('$request_lat') ) * 
    sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance FROM Coordinates HAVING distance < '$km' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5";
        $coordinates = array ();
        while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $coordinates[] = $e;
        }
        print (json_encode($coordinates));
```

Comment: Have you considered writing mysql function and use it in sql query?

Comment: i'm quite new to this whole DB thing. can u please elaborate?

Comment: is it for Junaio AR platform ?

Comment: Don't know what it is, so i'm guessing not. It's for, eventually, an iPhone & Android app

Comment: What @WojtekT means is that you wrote your function using PHP, but you could write it as a MySQL stored function using MySQL's programming language.  That way you could use it directly in your query, like this: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY shortest_distance_to(X1, Y1, X2, Y2) ASC, wich could be an awful lot faster than retrieving all the coordinates from your database to the PHP interpreter and comparing them there, especially if your dataset is very large.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using Google's algorithm:

```
$lon = //your longitude
$lat = //your latitude
$miles = //your search radius

$query = "SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$lon') ) + 
sin( radians('$lat') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM yourtable HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5"
```

`latitude` and `longitude` in this query are going to be your lat/lon column names.

Comment: Thanks,
I'm getting an error:
  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
$lon and $lat are received from a device's GPS, in the form of 35.21371 for example

Comment: Hmm. I don't see where the error would be coming from. I just ran this query again to be sure and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Edited the question to include the current code. can u check if there are problems in it?

Comment: The problem is you're not executing the query. `$runquery = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: Weird. i didn't use it before in other queries. It doesn't give an error anymore, but it just returns an empty array. and I tried with a large $km number aswell

Comment: `var_dump` the incoming $_POST latitudes and longitudes and make sure there are no pesky white spaces outside of them. Kill them with `trim()`

Comment: When I use them with different queries, such as INSERT, it works great, didn't change anything
where should I place the var_dump? in the query, or when getting the variables from the $_POST? If I only write SELECT * FROM... it also works

Comment: var_dump them before your query. the point being to make sure they are actually integers. if there are any hidden white spaces it will break your query. if that's not the solution, maybe someone else could find it because I don't know.

Comment: hopefully someone can help, because this didn't help either. Thanks a lot for your help any how!

Comment: After adding var_dump, i noticed it says string. so when I get the $_POST I now cast it to double (double) $_POST['longitude'] and it works. don't know why it sends them as string, but it works

Comment: Norse: can you post the link of Google's algorithm above? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered same problem lately. What i've decided was to write a mysql function to calculate distance and then use it in sql query.
Mysql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION distance(lat1 float, lon1 float, lat2 float, lon2 float) 
RETURNS float
RETURN ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2))+COS(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1)))*6371
```

If your `Coordinates` table has columns f.e. `latitude` and `longitude` then the code might look like this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Coordinates ORDER BY 
     distance(latitude, longitude, $lat, $lon) LIMIT 5";
```

Where `$lat` and `$lon` contain provided location.

Comment: Where does the CREATE FUNCTION goes? inside the PHP script, or using query inside the managing of the MySQL?

Comment: You have to execute that once using whatever tool you use to manage mysql database.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error that Access is denied when using the method inside SQLBuddy..

Comment: That may be because you database privileges don't allow you to create functions. In that case look into the answer provided by @Norse.

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to embed the sort in the query.

This wonderful tutorial will help you (and provides a query that serves your needs):
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql

Comment: It seems up now. Can you retry?