# Find current approximate location Postcode through mobile web

Tags: php, html, mobile

So far my searches have been fruitless, all I can find is commercial services. I need to find an easy way to find the current approximate "Postcode" using a mobile web based interface.

If anyone has experience to implement a free version, please kindly document here.

I suspect the process involved is

current location -> co-ordinates
co-ordinates -> Post code

Note: I currently have a list of Postcodes and co-orinates in a database, but what I am looking for is appropriate code to link current location to co-ordidates in database, preferably in php.

Ideally looking for code that does this.

http://www.whatsmypostcode.com

Update: I have found a free API service to transfer co-ordinates to Postcode.
http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api.php

Comment: Don't expect everything to be free, you'll need an API, API's runs on servers, servers needs electricity and electricity = $$.
Have you taken a look at google services ? They provide a nice API with some limit per day (for free).

Comment: Note: I already have my own server and database of postcodes and co-ordinates.

Comment: Ah ok, then [here's](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/geolocation_getcurrentposition.htm) a tutorial to get the coordinates, use AJAX to send it to the server, use PHP/MySQL to get [the nearest coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10771017/) and get the related postcode of it. Simple ? Now you have to code it :D

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL below is for `MySQL` but should be similar for others.

Basically it will return the postcode record that is closest to the provided
start point.

`$longitude` = The starting longitude
`$latitude`  = The starting latitude
`1.609344`   = Distance will be in miles, if you change this to 1 it will be KM

```
SELECT
  postcode, 
  latitude, 
  longitude,
  (
    6371.04 * acos(cos(pi()/2-radians(90-latitude)) 
    * cos(pi()/2-radians(90-$latitude)) 
    * cos(radians(longitude)-radians($longitude)) 
    + sin(pi()/2-radians(90-latitude)) 
    * sin(pi()/2-radians(90-$latitude))) / 1.609344 

  ) AS distance
FROM
  postcodes 
ORDER BY
  distance ASC
LIMIT
  1
```